# Create multiple copies of xlsx file with different file names on Mac Excel

Tags: excel, xlsx, duplication, excel-2011

1. I have a .xlsx file that contains 4 sheets filled with data and
   formulas etc.
2. I need to duplicate that .xlsx file 1000 times and save each file
   with a different name.
3. I have another .xlsx file containing the list of 1000 names that I
   would like these duplicates to be named when saved.
4. Is it possible for me to do this without manually copying the file 1000 times and renaming every one?
5. I am using excel on a Mac, not sure if this limits my options....

Comment: yes, you can easily do something from the "Terminal" command prompt to do this.

Comment: Are you open to a VBA solution?

Comment: I am open to any solution! I spent a few hours searching around and trying to do it through the terminal but failed miserably with the looping and renaming part of the duplication. Any tips would be appreciated.